# Understanding fully the proof of the uniqueness of a fixed-point

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration

I was reading the proof of the uniqueness of the fixed-point.

The uniqueness is stated as follows:

> ...
>
> If, in addition (to the fact that we know that $\exists$ a fixed-point in a range $[a, b]$), the derivative $g'(x)$ exists and there is a
> constant $p < 1$, such that the derivative satisfies $$|g'(x)| \leq p < 1 , \forall x \in (a, b)$$ then the fixed point $x^{*}$ is unique in this interval.

#### Proof

> Suppose there are two fixed-points $x^*$ and $y^*$, such that $g(x^*) = x^*$ and $g(y^*) = y^*$, then we want to show that $y^* = x^*$.
>
> We know that $g'(x) \leq p, \forall x \in (a, b)$
>
> $$|x^* - y^*| = |g(x^*) - g(y^*)| = |g'(\alpha)| * |x^* - y^*| \leq p |x^* - y^*|$$ where $\alpha$ is an intermediate value between $x^*$ and $y^*$.
>
> Obviously, the inequality can only hold with $p < 1 \iff x^* = y^*$.

I understood most of the things in this proof, except the most important (probably).

#### Questions

1. Why the inequality holds only if $p < 1$? Maybe it has something to do with the nature of $|g'(\alpha)|$? Or maybe to the nature of fixed points?
2. I understood that we are using the *mean value theorem* in the last equality, but why are we using $p$ there? (This is somehow a stupid question, but I like to hear your experienced opinions :)

---

**Edit**

Part of the source of my confusion is due to the fact that I interpreted wrongly the statement

> Obviously, the inequality can only hold with $p < 1 \iff x^* = y^*$

which is saying that the inequality holds when $p < 1$ if $x^* = y^* $ (and thus viceversa).

But I'm still confused why.

Comment: (1).The sentence beginning "Obviously..." is unclear and ungrammatical.(2). We use the MVT to get  $\alpha$ between $x^*$ and $y^*$ satisfying $g(x^*)-g(y^*)=g'(\alpha)(x^*-y^*)$....(3).We have  $|g'(\alpha)|\cdot |x^*-y^*|\leq p|x^*-y^*|$  (which is implied by $|g'|\leq p<1)$....(4). Combining the inequalities  from (2) and (3) with $|x^*=y^*|=|g(x^*)-g(y^*)|$  gives the main line of the proof, which implies $|x^*-y^*|\leq p|x^*-y^*|.$ But $p<1,$  so this  can't hold if $x^*\ne y^*,$ contradicting the hypothesis  $x^*\ne y^*.$  So the existence of two fixed points is untenable.

Answer (score 3):

We don't really need $p$. In fact we have the slightly stronger result

> If $I\subseteq \Bbb R$ is a (possibly unbounded) interval and $g\colon I\to I$ is continuous on $I$ and differentiable on the interior of $I$ and $g'(x)\ne 1$ for all $x$ in the interior of $I$, then $g$ has  at most one fixed point.

The proof is exactly the same: Suppose $g$ has two distinct fixpoints $x^*$ and $y^*$, where wlog. $x^*<y^*$. Then by the the intermediate value theorem
$$y^*-x^*=g(y^*)-g(x^*)=g'(\xi)\cdot(y^*-x^*)$$
for some $\xi\in(x^*,y^*)$. Dividing by the non-zero number $y^*-x^*$ produces $g'(\xi)=1$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

For Question 1, note that the inequality is

$$|x^*-y^*|\le p|x^*-y^*| \tag 1$$

If $x^*\ne y^*$, then upon dividing both sides of $(1)$ by $|x^*-y^*|$ reveals

$$1\le p$$

But $p< 1$, and so the contradiction implies that $x^*=y^*$.

Comment: Yes, that works too since we know that $|g'(x)|<1$.  You seem to understand perhaps better than you think you do!   So, well done.